# Get text of most recent notification with applescript

Tags: applescript

I would like to be able to grab the text of the most recent notification and pass it into an applescript variable. How can I do that?

Edit: here's what I have so far:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "NotificationCenter"
            tell first window
                set rawElements to UI elements
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

This gets me most of the way there, but it doesn't get me the body of the notification, just the label:

Here's the output:

> {static text "Macro Cancelled" of window 1 of application process
> "NotificationCenter" of application "System Events", image 1 of window
> 1 of application process "NotificationCenter" of application "System
> Events", scroll area 1 of window 1 of application process
> "NotificationCenter" of application "System Events", image 2 of window
> 1 of application process "NotificationCenter" of application "System
> Events"}

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to generate a *notification*:

```
display notification with title "Macro Cancelled" subtitle "Cancel All Macros."
```

In the example *notification*, **Cancel All Macros.** is in:

```
static text of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "NotificationCenter"
```

**Using:**

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get value of ¬
        static text of ¬
        scroll area 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        process "NotificationCenter"
```

**It returns:**

```
{"Cancel All Macros.", ""}
```

As you can see what's returned is a `list` and will need to be process as such.

Note however, in this example, **Cancel All Macros.** is actually `static text 1 of scroll area 1` and `static text 2 of scroll area 1`, which is blank, is when `display notification` uses:

- **display notification** [text] : the body text of the notification

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

---

**With Error Handling:**

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    if exists window 1 of ¬
        process "Notification Center" then ¬
        get value of ¬
            static text of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "NotificationCenter"
```

Comment: This returns `"System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of process \"NotificationCenter\". Invalid index."` if the notification isn't visible on screen, but rather living in the notification centre list off screen.

Comment: @CJK, As the example shows the notification being generated, the window exists for the demonstration of the example. See the note at the bottom of the answer.